Power Automate remove email address duplicates when emailing multiple users named on a SharePoint list
Good afternoon all,
Im struggling with a Power flow that notifies multiple users based on the ‘review date’ of a document library on SPO.
Setup:
I have two columns, Lead Author and Contact, both of which can contain multiple users. (See below). In the SPO document library i currently have two items (Fire and Flood .docx) that match the review date criteria to trigger the flow for each, and therefore an email to be sent for each item.

My flow is as follows:





The Issue:
Each email for the two items that match the flow criteria contain the contact details twice.

Ideally, id expect the Lead Authors and the Contact's to appear once in the To and CC fields of the email.
Im sure this must be due to the array being immediately converted to a string but im not familiar enough with the tool to see a way out of this. Any help would be much appreciated.
UPDATE 03/04/2024
On advice from another forum, i have used the Join() and union() functions to remove duplicates from the 'To' and 'CC' fields in the Send Email dialogue. But. Looking at the same Document library from before, now with 3 test documents and a combination of LeadAuthors and Contacts we have:

Note: Specifically following the top document, 'Flood', it has Lead Author as Daniel Gregory and the Contact as Test 365. Other documents have other combinations of Lead Authors and Contacts, specifically including the DEV1 DG user.
All 3 of these documents trigger the flow as they all fit the same criteria/trigger. When the email(s) are received, specifically the reminder email regarding the 'Flood' document - I see the following:

The 'To' and 'CC' fields seem to include the contact details of all the documents that triggered at the same time. Similarly, the other two reminders setup for the other two documents include the same contacts in the To and CC fields.
Im beginning to think i've set this up all wrong, and not sure how to proceed from here. Again, it feels very array related.

Does it really matter? I ask because in my experience, the user will only receive the email once anyway, no?

No i suppose it doesnt matter to much at this scale. I worry it'll become unwieldly if there are lots of documents and lots of duplicate email address' in the emails.

You could use some more advanced operations in the Advanced Data Operations connector to get a distinct list if you’re really keen.

Apologies, Skin - im quite new to this. None the less, ive updated my post to reflect 'what is going on' a little clearer.

You can use a union function to get unique values. Before you can use that function you can convert the LeadAuthorEmailAddress string variable value into an array via a split function. After you have a new array you can join the values back together as a string value with the semi colon separator.
In your To field use the below expression
join(union(split(variables('LeadAuthorEmailAddress'), ';'), split(variables('LeadAuthorEmailAddress'), ';')), ';')

